# How to copy files & run commands on remote Azure Win VM?

Tags: azure, batch-file, psexec, azure-virtual-network

From my local Windows command prompt, I can copy files to local Windows machines, and run commands on the local Windows machines with psexec. (For example, launching .bat files). I can also start/stop and query services on the Windows machines, for example with sc \machineIP query (servicename).

I am learning to be able to do the same thing with a stock Windows machine hosted in Azure.

Having created a stock Windows Server VM in Azure from the command line, what more must I do? Currently on the Azure VM, for testing, I have:

- Turned off the Firewall
- Disabled simple file sharing wizard
- Shared C, with permissions for 'everyone'
- Started 'remote registry' service
- Added registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy with value of 1 (hex)

I am able to RDP to the machine without a problem, with the given public IP address, username, and password.

I note that I cannot access: \publicIP\c$

And psexec returns 'The network path was not found. Make sure the default admin$ share is enabled on (publicIP)' when running the command:

```
psexec.exe \\(publicIP) -u(username) -p (password) -i 1 cmd /c c:\runMe.bat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure portal, navigate into the resource group where your VM resides. Select the 'Network Security Group' profile used by your VM  (eg, yourVMnameNSG) -> edit -> add inbound security rules.

eg:

```
Name: psexec    
Source: any
Destination: any
Service: Custom (Any/135)
Action: allow
```

Repeat for required services

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Please mark it as answer so that other community members will be benefited.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I can 'accept my own answer tomorrow' apparently.